# Does Magento allow order and shipping restrictions by country for specific items on the product level?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.4

the product’s page would have a “restricted countries” tab, where we can select countries that the product **cannot** ship to.

Comment: country like "pakistan,india,Iran,etc" and then if i select pakistan then in second dropdown cities list appear like which city you ristrict of with perticular city.

Comment: plz help if you know some thing or work on this kind of module plz share.

Answer (score 2):

Nope I am afraid recently coded the functionality for a project: Few pointers how I tackled the issue:

- You will have to modify the addToCart
  functionality to introduce your
  logic. Rewrite
  Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction()
- You will also need to alter the OnePageController Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveBillingAction and saveShippingAction to confirm that the address choosen are not restriced
- You will also need to alter Mage_Checkout_MultishippingController::addressesPostAction to do the same address checking during multi shipping checkout.

Admin Changes

- You will need a product attribute called restricted_countries ...you will need to set some source and backend models to poplulate the countries in the multi select list in the product tab

I hope this puts you on the right path ... good luck.

Comment: Your welcome a vote up or a tick the answer as correct would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think you should go multi-website and have the product selection, prices and delivery prices setup per currency (or region).

You then should put some GeoIP code on the index.php so that you have one URL for all of your websites.

In that way the person from region A sees the subset of products for their region based on their currency, e.g. ₡7.99 instead of an auto-converted ₡7.57, region B sees a different subset of products e.g. ₱14.99 instead of auto-converted ₱14.23 and so on.

Price points do matter if your site is to be popular, making money and a long term investment then you need price points not auto-converted prices or foreign currency only.

The multi-store, multi-website arrangement is out-of-the-box, easy to setup and with minimal burden on catalog inventory management. Work within the software and the methods available, don't reinvent the wheel.